# amazon emr - does creating a cluster use data transfer out?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

I am using aws with emr over ec2 and getting tons of charges for data transfer out, about 900 gb for a few days, but I don't send any data out.

The only thing I am doing is creating an emr cluster and downloading data from s3 to it.

I found [this](https://blog.cloudability.com/aws-data-transfer-costs-what-they-are-and-how-to-minimize-them/) about costs and see that data transfer out to the internet Is not supposed to happen when you are not sending any data!

I keep seeing multiple charges for data transfer out to many aws regions and to the internet, I can't find any reference for a reason to it. what can it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely is that you're accessing an S3 bucket in a different region. Either for your data or for writing EMR cluster logs.

There are a couple of ways to diagnose this. First, of course, is to look at your EMR cluster config.

Second is to enable [VPC flow logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html), which will tell you the exact source and destination for your data. These may, however, be limited: if you're running all traffic through a NAT then they'll just show the NAT, not the ultimate source/destination.

A third approach is to use a security group that prevents outbound connections, and look in your logs to see what fails.